# Rails front end validation on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a site where users can add tags to pictures similar to imgur.  I would like to implement live front end validation.  I want tags to only contain letters and have a minimum and maximum length.  I also want to disable to submit button when these front end validations are failing.  I would like to show error messages in tooltip style and I want the tooltip to popup as soon as the input box doesn't meet the validation criteria.

This is what part of my view looks like (show.html.erb):

```
<div class="add-tag">
            <p>
              <%= form_tag add_tag_path, remote:true do %>
                <%= text_field_tag :tag, nil, placeholder: 'Add tag', id: 'add-tag' %>
                <%= submit_tag 'Add' %>
              <% end %>
            </p>
</div>
```

I think I can get tooltips with bootstrap.  I think the best way to get the front end validations to work would be with jquery and .keyup() but I don't really know how I would get it to work how I want as described above.  I'm pretty new to jquery.

EDIT:

I got the front end validation working with jquery validate plugin.  Here is the code from application.js:

```
$('#custom-tag').validate({
    onkeyup: function (element, event) {
            if (event.which === 9 && this.elementValue(element) === "") {
                return;
            } else {
                this.element(element);
            }
    },
    rules: {
      tag: {
        minlength: 5
      }
    }
  });
```

Is there a way to disable the submit button when the the validation is failing (I do have back end validations setup)? And how can I get the error message to show up in a bootstrap tooltip?

EDIT2:

I made some progress.  I found some code and my application.js file looks like this now:

```
$('#custom-tag').validate({
    onkeyup: function (element, event) {
            if (event.which === 9 && this.elementValue(element) === "") {
                return;
            } else {
                this.element(element);
            }
    },

    showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
        this.defaultShowErrors();                            

          // destroy tooltips on valid elements                              
          $("." + this.settings.validClass)
              .tooltip("destroy");            

        // add/update tooltips 
        for (var i = 0; i < errorList.length; i++) {
            var error = errorList[i];

            $("#" + error.element.id)
                .tooltip({ trigger: "focus", placement: "right" })
                .attr("data-original-title", error.message)                
          }
    },


    rules: {
      tag: {
        minlength: 5
      }
    }
  });
```

The tooltip only triggers when I click outside of the textbox and then click the textbox again and the nontooltip error message is still displaying.

EDIT3:

I found a [plugin](https://github.com/Thrilleratplay/jquery-validation-bootstrap-tooltip) to replace error messages with bootstrap tooltip.  My application.js file code now looks like this:

```
$('#custom-tag').validate({
    onkeyup: function (element, event) {
            if (event.which === 9 && this.elementValue(element) === "") {
                return;
            } else {
                this.element(element);
            }
    },

    rules: {
      tag: {
        minlength: 5,
        number: true
}
    },

    tooltip_options: {
      tag: { placement: 'right' }
    }
  });
```

The tooltip is now flashing with each keypress until the tooltip disappears.  Any way to fix this?

EDIT4:

Setting `animation: false` in tooltip_options fixed the flicker.  Guess I answered all my questions.  Should I delete this question?

Comment: There could be several validate plugins.  Please post a link to the exact one you're using.

Comment: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to validate on the backend anyhow because you cannot trust user submitted data regardless of front end validation attempts.  That said, for the purposes of UX, it is nice for the user to realize he's screwing up BEFORE he sends data, so, something like the following:

```
var el = $('#add-tag');

el.on('keyup', fixtag);

function fixtag() {

    var val = el.val();

    // fix the value

    el.val(val); // replace it

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's going on here.  I see that the fix tag function is called on keyup.  I think I need a tooltip to popup immediately after a non-letter is pressed or when the string becomes longer than 25 characters.  How would I do this?

Comment: I wouldn't use a tool tip.  I would tell the user before hand via an info box or something explaining what valid tags are.  So when they type a bad character and it gets removed automatically, they'll know why.  If you really want to display tooltips and all that jazz, there are tons of examples on the internet, especially in bootstrap/jquery documentation.  http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.5/docs/javascript/#tooltips and https://api.jquery.com/keyup/ as for an elaborate working example, I do not think I have the time to produce at the moment, but perhaps later.